# Generate all permutations of a given String in D

Tags: d

I'm trying to write a program in D that generates all permutations for a given string.  I've been trying to use the function nextPermutation, but it's only compatible with ints.  I can't get it to work with a char array.  I was wondering if someone could help point me in the right direction?  This is what I have so far:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.algorithm.sorting: nextPermutation;

void main()
{
    char array[] = {'a','b','c'};

do
{
        writeln(array);

} while (nextPermutation(array));

}
```

Answer (score 3):

So it isn't only compatible with ints, it is anything that Phobos considers "bidirectional" and "swappable" - an array it can reverse easily and swap individual elements, and it considers plain string to be non-swappable due to UTF-8 encoding. Due to its variable length element encoding, swapping two chars may require reshuffling the entire array, which would be far more expensive than the function allows.

Thus, the easiest way to make this work is to use a type which Phobos considers to be swappable: a UTF-32 string, aka `dchar[]`.

If you just change your `char` to `dchar`, it will work.

You might also want to change your array syntax from C style to D style:

```
dchar[] array = ['a','b','c'];
```

There you go.

So, I said "it considers" because this is kinda a controversial library decision. I'd argue UTF-32 isn't really swappable for a similar reason that UTF-8 isn't - there can be paired elements and changing their order can corrupt the data. But you don't need to worry about that for simple cases like you have.

Comment: Yep, `auto array = ["one", "two", "three"];` will work too.